# Heroku installs wrong dependencies (only latest)

Tags: python, heroku

During deployment of a flask app, I found out that Heroku doesn’t respect the versions of dépendances specified in requirements.txt:

```
Flask==2.1.1
flask-restx==0.5.1
...
```

Heroku install only the latest version:

```
Flask==2.2.2
...
```

By using the console through the Heroku web interface and executing `pip install flask==2.1.0`, I'm also getting the latest version of Flask (2.2.2) installed:

```
Collecting flask==2.1.0
  Downloading Flask-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 95.2/95.2 kB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask==2.1.0) (4.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask==2.1.0) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask==2.1.0) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.0 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask==2.1.0) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask==2.1.0) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask==2.1.0) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->flask==2.1.0) (3.8.1)
Installing collected packages: flask
  Attempting uninstall: flask
    Found existing installation: Flask 2.2.2
    Uninstalling Flask-2.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-2.2.2
Successfully installed flask-2.2.2
```

Comment: Heroku (or, rather, `pip`) definitely _does_ respect versions in `requirements.txt`, assuming it installs dependencies with `pip`.  Do you also have a `Pipfile`? Because if you do, Heroku will use Pipenv and install the dependencies from your `Pipfile.lock` instead.

Comment: @Chris, you're right! I have a ```Pipfile```. As soon as as I removed it, Heroku installed the right versions of my dependencies. Thanks.